# How to proof the reason?

Tags: proof-explanation

I have this statement:

> If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d},$ prove that
>   $\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{c+d}{c-d}$

I tried to add 1, multiply 1 and nothing.

My development was:

$\frac{a}{b} - \frac{b}{b} = \frac{c}{d} - \frac{d}{d}$

$\frac{a-b}{b} = \frac{c-d}{d}$

$\frac{b}{a-b} = \frac{d}{c-d}$ (I raised to $^{-1}$)

So far I have arrived, without much success.
How can I prove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just cross multiply: that's the easiest approach.

Comment: Note:  You actually need to specify that $a \ne b$ and $\frac ab \ne 1$.  Other wise the result is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is given

$$\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}$$ from here we get

$$2bc=2ad$$ and then

$$ac+bc-ad-bd=ac+ad-bc-bd$$
and this is $$(a+b)(c-d)=(c+d)(a-b)$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you! , how did you come up with the solution? Any algebraic trick?

Comment: I used the method working backwards by Polya.

Comment: Thanks, very useful

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$$
write  $$\frac{a}{b}+1 = \frac{c}{d}+1$$
$$\frac{a+b}{b} = \frac{c+d}{d}$$

also if $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$$
then $$\frac{b}{a} = \frac{d}{c}$$
write $$1-\frac{b}{a} =1- \frac{d}{c}$$
 $$\frac{a-b}{a} = \frac{c-d}{c}$$
we first obtained that $$\frac{a+b}{b} = \frac{c+d}{d}$$
$$\frac{(a+b)a}{(a-b)b} = \frac{(c+d)c}{(c-d)d}$$
also $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$$
thus 
$$\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{c+d}{c-d}$$

Comment: Is it valid to divide them?, i.e $\frac{(a+b)a}{(a-b)b} = \frac{(c+d)c}{(c-d)d}$ ? I did not know at all.

Comment: yes it is valid what it is that is stopping you to divide them

Comment: You need to consider the cases that what you are dividing by is equal to zero. If $\frac ab = \frac ac \ne 0$ then $\frac {(a+b) a}{(a-b}b = \frac {(c+d)c}{(c-d)d}$ and we can divide both sides by $\frac ab$  But then we must consider if $\frac ab = 0$.  Then $a = 0$ and $c =0$ and then $\frac {a+b}{a-b} = \frac {b}{-b}=-1=\frac {d}-{-d} = \frac {c+d}{c-d}$ so that is okay.

Comment: I already knew that because the only thing that stopping us from dividing is the denominator should not be zero here it wasn't the case also I want op to understand this concept himself

Comment: Likewise when you divide both sides of $\frac{a+b}{b} = \frac{c+d}{d}$ by $\frac{a-b}{a} = \frac{c-d}{c}$ we must consider if $\frac{a-b}{a} = \frac{c-d}{c}= 0$.  In which case $a = b; c= d$ and  .... the statement we want to prove actually is *NOT* true.

Comment: Mmm.... okay, but the OP asked "is it valid to divide them" and I think the honest answer should be.  "It's valid if they are not equal to zero".

Comment: Ok, should I edit my answer?  I answered the question fully so I wanted to understand himself that concept

Answer (score 0):

Actually the result is not true if $a = b$ and $\frac ab =\frac cd =  1$ and $c = d$.  Then $\frac {a+b}{a-b}$ and $\frac {c+d}{c-d} $ are both undefined and not equal to each other.

.......

Three ideas:

1) Proportions:

$\frac ab = \frac cd$ means there is some ratio so that $a = cr$ and $b = dr$.  (That's clear, isn't it?  $\frac {cr}{dr} = \frac ab$ for all $r$ and if [assuming $a\ne 0; c\ne 0$] then if $r = \frac ac$ means $\frac ab = \frac {cr}{dr} =  \frac {c\frac ac}{dr} = \frac a{dr}$.  So $dr = b$.)

So $\frac {a+b}{a-b} = \frac {cr +dr}{cr - dr} = \frac {r(c+d)}{r(c-d)}=\frac {c+d}{c-d}$.

[Note:  we should take $a=0$ as a possiblity.  $\frac 0b = \frac cd \implies c = 0$ so $\frac {a+b}{a-b} = \frac {b}{-b} = - 1$ and $\frac {c+d}{c-d}=\frac d{-d} = -1$.]

2) Substitution:

$\frac ab = \frac cd$ so $a = \frac {bc}d$ (or any of other variable)

So $\frac {a+ b}{a-b} = \frac {\frac {bc}d + b}{\frac {bc}d - b} ==\frac {b(\frac cd +1)}{b(\frac cd - 1)}= \frac {\frac cd +1}{\frac cd - 1}==\frac {d(\frac cd +1)}{d(\frac cd - 1)} = \frac {c + d}{c-d}$.

3)  Consequences:

$\frac ab =\frac cd \implies ad = bc$.

And $\frac {a+b}{a-b} = \frac{c+d}{c-d} \iff$

$(a+b)(c-d) = (c+d)(a-b) \iff$

$ac + bc -ad - bd = ac +ad - bc = bd \iff$

$2bc = 2ad \iff$

$bc = ad$

And we determined that that is true.

(NOTE:  It is *!!!!!!VITALLLLLLLY!!!!!!* important the we note that every step in that argument is an if *AND ONLY* if statement.  Otherwise we can *NOT EVER* start with what we want to prove.  If you *EVER* try to to do a proof where you start with your conclusion and get a true result and conclude your conclusion was true and your statements were not if and only if statements, I will reach through my computer screen and pound your head to the table.)

(Less important but still important.  We can not end with $bc = ad \iff \frac ab = \frac cd$ as it is possible that $b=0$ or $d=0$ and it will not be true that $\frac ab = \frac cd$.  In particular we coulde have $a=0; d=5; b=0;c = 6$ and it *certainly* isnt true that $\frac 00 = \frac 65$.  We *could* say $bc = ad \iff \frac ab = \frac cd$ or $bc = ad = 0$.)

... or less dramatic than threatening to pound heads into table:

Once we figured this, we work in the *real* direction:

$\frac ab = cd \implies$

$ad = bc \implies$

$2ad = 2bc \implies$

$ad -bc = bc - ad \implies$

$ac + ad - bc - bd = ac +bc -ad -bd \implies$

$a(c+d) - b(c+d) = c(a+b) - d(a+b) \implies$

$(a-b)(c+d) = (c-d)(a+b)$

Assumming $a - b \ne 0$ and $c-d \ne 0$ then

$\frac {a+b}{a-b} = \frac {c+d}{c-d}$.

However if $a - b = 0$ then $a = b$ and $\frac ab = 1$ and $\frac cd = 1$ and $c = d$ and then.... well, the result simply isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

Any identity similar to yours -- involving 'direct sums/differences' of fractions, can be proved by multiplying out the denominator (of the identity to be proved), rearranging and cancelling terms and getting $ad-bc=0$. All of the operations above are easily done the opposite way, which builds up the proof. (Although it will look like a proof out of the blue!)

For yours, write the following sequence of equations *backwards*.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a+b}{a-b}&=\frac{c+d}{c-d}\\
(a+b)(c-d)&=(c+d)(a-b)\\
ac+bc-ad-bd&=ac+ad-bc-bd\\
2bc&=2ad\\
ad&=bc\\
\end{align}
$$

... with the original equation on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Let, $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=k$ or, $a=bk,c=dk$. Now consider the LHS:$$\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{bk+b}{bk-b}=\frac{k+1}{k-1}$$

Also, $$\frac{c+d}{c-d}=\frac{dk+d}{dk-d}=\frac{k+1}{k-1}~~~~~~~~~\boxed{}$$